# Таймер появляется только после обновления страницы JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Есть такая проблема: Написал таймер, но при переходе с другой страницы он появляется только после обновления страницы, хотя сам таймер время считает

Собственно листинг самой страницы:

```
<?php
    include "../script/func/function.php";
    check_coock();
    check_coock_testing();
    $exit = '<a href="../script/kill_coock.php">Выход</a>';
    $admin = '<a href="../pages/admin.php">Админ</a>';
    $admin_hr = '<hr class="admin_hr">';
    $num = get_num(4);
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="https://amt.rosminzdrav.ru/theme/image.php/adaptable/theme/1605257379/favicon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style-main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style-testing.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Тестирование</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo" class="time"></p> 
    <div class="up">
         <text class="goto_exit"></text>
         <div class="exit_div">
          <?php
            if (isset($_COOKIE["admin"])) {
             echo $exit;             
             echo $admin_hr;             
             echo $admin;
            } else {
              echo $exit;
            }
          ?> 
         </div>
         <img src="../images/index/f1.png" alt="" class="user_img">
         <text class="up_text">
             <?php
                 echo $_COOKIE["name"];
                 echo " ";
                 echo $_COOKIE["surname"];
             ?>
         </text>
     </div>
<header>
        <div>
            <text>Тестирование - 1 -й этап</text>
        </div>
        
</header>
     

<p id="demo" class="time"></p> 
<?php
    // $mas = array("");
    // for ($i=0; $i < 60; $i++) { 
    //     $rand_id = rand(1, 2286);
    //     for ($j=0; $j < count($mas); $j++) {
    //         if ($mas[$i] = $rand_id) {
    //             $rand_id = rand(1, 2286);
    //         } else {
    //             $mas[count($mas) + 1] = $rand_id;
    //         }    
    //     }
    //     var_dump(get_quest($mas[$i]));
    // }
    var_dump($num);
?>
<footer></footer>
<script>   
let countDownDate = <?php echo $_COOKIE["hours"]?>;
var x = setInterval(function() {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  var distance = (countDownDate * 1000) - now;
  var hours = 0;
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    if (minutes >= 10) {
        if (seconds >= 10){
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Оставшееся время " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Оставшееся время " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":0" + seconds;
        }
    } else {
        if (seconds >= 10) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Оставшееся время " + hours + ":0" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Оставшееся время " + hours + ":0" + minutes + ":0" + seconds;
        }        
    }

  if (distance < 0) {clearInterval(x);document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Время истелко";}}, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А что в консоли ошибки или что? Вот в первый раз мне кажется что там нет куки на сервере.

Comment: Чтобы с большей вероятностью получить ответ, нужно привести его в порядок, разбить js и php на отдельные блоки, убрать ненужные части кода. Копаться в этой каше кода не очень хочется

Comment: В консоли ничего не выводится. Все отлично работает, но выводится только после обновления.

Comment: Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). В противном случае невозможно дать объективный ответ

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил. Просто надо было добавить в функцию создания куки нынешнего времени данную строчку кода header("Refresh:0");

Тем самым получаю такой код
Функция check_coock_testing - Проверка на существование куки

```
{
    if (isset($_COOKIE["hours"])) {
        // relax man
        return false;
    } else {
        get_time_coock();
        header("Refresh:0");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Функция get_time_coock - создать куки с нынешнем временем + 1 час

```
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
    $hours = time();
    $hours += 3600000;
    setcookie("hours", $hours, time() + 7200, "/");
}
```